# scrapy with django : how to use foreign key

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I want to use scrapy with django,but I don't know how to deal with django foreignkey
My database is postgreSQL

Please guide me. Thank you.

models.py:

```
class ShoppingApple(models.Model):
    link        = models.URLField(max_length=255)      
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)     

class ImageApple(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingApple)    
    image =models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

pipelines.py:

```
class ShopPipeline(object):
    if isinstance(item, Shop_appleItem):  
        shopping = item.save(commit=False) 
        shopping.save()
        return item

    if isinstance(item, Shop_apple_imgItem):
        shopping = item.save(commit=False) 
        shopping.save()
        return item
```

spider like this:

```
def parse(self,response):
    item = Shopping_appleItem()
    product = Shopping_apple_imgItem()
    sel = Selector(response)
    item['link'] = sel.css("  ").extract()
    item['title'] = sel.css(" ").extract()
    product['image'] = sel.css(" ").extract()
    yield item
    yield product
```

When I run my scrapy ,the error is :

```
    django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "article_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, http://test...).
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have null value somewhere?
Try with setting the default to null just for test.

```
ALTER TABLE article SET DEFAULT NULL
```

[PostgreSQL ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html)

Then run again to see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using South or any other tool for migration(or Django 1.7+) ? If so, just update the models to :

```
class ImageApple(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingApple)    
    image =models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

generate and run the migration, this should do the trick.

Comment: I found that maybe it is because I didn't save the ````article```` ,but I stiil don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

What i do is use a regular scrapy item (not a django item, that thing is quite limited) and just create the object manually and add what i need.

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    image_url = scrapy.Field()
```

And handle the download manually and create the objects by myself:

```
object = Object.objects.create(foo="something")
object.save()
self.image_url = item['image_url']
self.get_remote_image(object)
```

You can get images easily with urllib:

def get_remote_image(self, object):

```
if self.image_url:
    myopener = MyOpener()
    page = myopener.retrieve(self.image_url)
    response = page[0]
    image = open(response)

    extension = os.path.splitext(image.name)[1]
    picture = Picture(object=object)
    picture.save()
    picture.picture.save('new' + extension, File(image))
```

I tried to do that with django items but got tired of trying and found this way. It is not hard to implement and allows way more freedom on how to create your objects.
Don't forget to add `django.setup()` to your scrapper's settings.py.